# Using certificate security for only parts of your ASP.Net website

Tags: asp.net, security, ssl, iis-7, certificate

We have a company website that is both client facing and used internally. My problem is that I want only 1 or 2 pages to be accessed if a certificate exists. The certificate will be installed on our machines in the office. External customers should not be able to access this page.

What is the best way to do this?

I am using ASP.Net 4.0 with IIS-7

Comment: Welcome to SO what kind of certificate it is. Is it a `SSL` certificate.

Comment: An idea could be define role of the users. And for a particular role allow those pages. Here is a link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: it is SLL. Unfortunately the boss would like only 1 or 2 pages to be viewed only if a certificate is installed locally. I think this is so that any ex-employees cannot login etc. Restrict by IP Address is a solution but not perfect in his opinion.